# Openstack with vmware esxi as hypervisor?

Tags: vmware, openstack, hypervisor

I have changed hypervisor of my openstack(Grizzly) to vmware esxi.

When I create an Ibuntu in openstack dashboard, it works well and I can see the instance in esxi, but when I created a Windows 7 instance, 'blue screen' occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely disk driver issues. Go to your ESXi host directly, create a new Win7 VM (No need to install Windows, just the VM creation). Check the disk controller (LSI Logic???) and compare this to the VM that is created by Openstack.